# How to draw a y-axis and x-axis line in the center of a 4x4 grid?

Tags: html, css

I currently have 4 items with content in them. I am trying to draw an x-axis and y-axis line in the center of the 4 items without using the border property. So far I have tried using nth-child():after, but I haven't been able to get them exactly centered and to stay within the section they are in. Here is an example of what is supposed to look like:

```css
ul {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Here is how I've tried doing it using the :after property.

```css
ul {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

li:nth-child(1):after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   margin: 40px;
   height: 1px;
   width: 80%;
   background: #000;
}

li:nth-child(3):after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 50%;
   margin: 40px;
   width: 1px;
   height: 80%;
   background: #000;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use outline and it's easy:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding:0;
  border: 50px solid transparent; /* replace padding with transparent border */
  overflow:hidden; /* here */
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  outline:1px solid; /* and here */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Also like below using gradient

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows:1fr;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) center/100% 1px,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) center/1px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform: translate(-50%)` along with `left:50%` to center align the lines on 1st and 3rd nth-child.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px; /* control spacing*/
}

li:nth-child(1):after {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

li:nth-child(3):after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

li:nth-child(1):after,
li:nth-child(3):after {
  background: #000;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%); /* center align lines */
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        TITLE
      </h4>
      <p>Nulla aliqua irure in enim ex eu ex culpa Lorem. Veniam cillum dolore ea sit ea aute consequat aute id. Lorem qui adipisicing ea culpa fugiat ea labore excepteur. Deserunt fugiat elit labore dolore.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! The transform property helped the horizontal line get centered, but the y-axis line is moved to the very top of my page outside of where that section is.

Comment: I am currently playing tweaking it right now on my page, but that definitely solved it within this snippet.

Comment: Is there a way for the vertical line to not move all the way to the top of the page?